# Blender player lauched by command line

Tags: command-line, linux

I am looking for a list of arguments that is possible to give to blenderplayer by command line on linux. I need to open a blender file with blenderplayer in a specific scene. I cannot find anywhere!

Comment: Sorry maybe if you tell us more about what you want to actually achieve there would be more ideas coming from viewers. I really don't understand why you need to tweak something that already has strong system of customization via python scripting. Best regards

Comment: Did you read the output from `blenderplayer --help` ?

Comment: @ideasman42 I tried 'blenderplayer --help' but it seems that the command doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look [here](https://helpmanual.io/man1/blenderplayer/) or [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/blenderplayer.1.html) or execute the command `blenderplayer -h`, you can check the list you are looking for.

usage:
`blenderplayer [-w [w h l t]] [-f [fw fh fb ff]] [-g gamengineoptions] [-s stereomode] [-m aasamples] filename.blend`.